# Updated DNS zone can't be seen from my local network

Tags: dns, ip, hosting

I have updated a domain name DNS zone on 123-reg.co.uk where I bought the domain name. I have only updated blog A record to different hosting(IP)

On my PC home (windows) or another PC in the same network (MAC or phone) when I visit the blog.domain.com still shows old IP address (hosting).

But when I connect to 4g on my phone or try from different network, they visit new IP (hosting)

I `did ipconfig /flushdns`
I have restarted the router at home.
I have cleared browser cache

Why do you think the reason is? How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why do DNS changes take 24-48 hours to propagate?

> Every domain has two name servers assigned to it and these are the
>   only two name servers that hold records for the domain. However, when
>   another server somewhere else in the world, queries the name servers
>   for DNS records, it will often keep a local copy of the DNS record so
>   that next time it needs to know what IP address the domain resolves
>   to, it already has the answer.
>
> **Once changes are made to the actual DNS records on the two name
>   servers that are assigned to your domain, these changes will gradually
>   filter through the other servers in the world so that everything is up
>   to date and it is this process that normally takes 24-48 hours.**
>
> [image]

Source [Why do people always tell me that my DNS changes take 24-48 hours to propagate?](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domain-Configuration/why-do-people-always-tell-me-that-my-dns-changes-take-24-48-hours-to-propagate-2653/)

---

#### What can I do if my ISP DNS servers have not picked up the change yet?

If the DNS servers of your ISP have not yet picked up the change you can change your DNS to OpenDNS.

You should be able to change this in your router, but test locally first.

Comment: but everywhere is okay except my own house. Just one place. Is this why is happining?

Comment: Perhaps the dns servers of your ISP are not very good? What happens if you change your dns to [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/home-internet-security/opendns-ip-addresses/)? You should be able to change this in your router, but test locally first ...

Comment: thank you very much. that fixes the problem. So, I understand why it had not been reflected on my home network. Because my ISP sucks:) thank you.